# Mysql sort BY number of filled columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm comparing prices of products from `3` different website. So i have `3` different prices. If website doesn't offer that product, its price is empty.

**MySQL looks like this:**

```
**id | name | price_1 | price_2 | price 3**
```

I would like to sort it from products, which are available at all 3 websites. To products, that are available at just one website.

And I can't figure out how to approach this!

Comment: Just use ORDER BY price_1, price_2, price_3

Comment: It would be a lot easier if the data structure was sensibly normalized.  Then you could just `COUNT` the records on the joined table and sort by the count.

Comment: @antony That would rank products, which are available only at the first website, higher than those which are available at the second AND the third.

Comment: `ORDER BY 3 - (ISNULL(price_1) + ISNULL(price_2) + ISNULL(price_3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the empty fields have NULL value, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM sometable ORDER BY ISNULL(price_1) + ISNULL(price_2) + ISNULL(price_3) DESC;
```

But a more sensible solution would be:

- You have one table, which contains the products
- You have another
  table, which contains the product's ID, the price and a value which
  indicates which website provided that price.

Benefits:

- You only have to `COUNT(*)` the entries of a product in the second table to find out on how many it is listed
- You can change the number of websites any time without changing a table

Comment: not DESC, change ASC

Comment: Then you would have those with only one entry first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, (IF(price_1 IS NULL,0,1) + IF(price_2 IS NULL,0,1) + IF(price_3 IS NULL,0,1))  AS odr FROM `test1` ORDER BY odr DESC
```